# ionic 2 can i install basic dependencies globally?

Tags: node.js, npm, ionic2, npm-install

I'm new in ionic 2. For some reasons i want to install following packages globally in Ionic 2, but i`onic start myapp --v2` this command internally run `npm install` and install all packages in current app directory.

My package.json

```
{
    "dependencies": {
      "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.4",
      "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.4",
      "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.4",
      "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.4",
      "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.4",
      "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.4",
      "@angular/forms": "0.2.0",
      "es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
      "ionic-angular": "2.0.0-beta.11",
      "ionic-native": "1.3.10",
      "ionicons": "3.0.0",
      "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
      "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
      "zone.js": "^0.6.12"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
      "del": "2.2.0",
      "gulp": "3.9.1",
      "gulp-watch": "4.3.5",
      "ionic-gulp-browserify-typescript": "2.0.0",
      "ionic-gulp-fonts-copy": "^1.0.0",
      "ionic-gulp-html-copy": "^1.0.0",
      "ionic-gulp-sass-build": "^1.0.0",
      "ionic-gulp-scripts-copy": "^2.0.0",
      "ionic-gulp-tslint": "^1.0.0",
      "tslint-ionic-rules": "^0.0.3",
      "run-sequence": "1.1.5"
    },
    "cordovaPlugins": [
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
      "cordova-plugin-console",
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
      "cordova-plugin-device",
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
      "ionic-plugin-keyboard"
    ],
    "cordovaPlatforms": [],
    "name": "myapp",
    "description": "myapp: An Ionic project"
  }
```

**I'm trying to install the dependencies in package.json globally**. But every time app created this dependencies downloaded in `node_modules` folder.

I don't want `node_module` folder download every time when i'm creating new app.

Comment: i think it is not possible without node module folder

Comment: Improved formatting.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't want node_module folder download every time when i'm creating
>   new app

That's not possible, but even if it would be possible, it would be a very dangerous and caotic design; `package.json` isn't meant to be used for global dependencies.

If any of your apps needs a different version of some of the dependencies (for compatibility reasons for instance), it would be impossible to keep different versions of the same dependency in the same `node_modules` folder. And even more, if you'd have different `package.json` files for each project, and run npm `install` in one of them, that would change the dependencies that all the other apps use (because they would be global), causing some of them not to work properly anymore.